# Are web hosting different from deployment platforms?

Tags: web, web-deployment

I'm asking this question because I've noticed that it's possible to deploy an app that's on a github repository on some other deployment platform. Are they different?

Comment: Where are you seeing the term "deployment platform?"   I'm very familiar with deploying a site to your web host, but I've never heard it called a "deployment platform."

Comment: In zeet node you can deploy an app that's hosted on Github. Am I understanding this correctly, does github act as the host here? Or is the term different? @StephenOstermiller